# Use Case for Course Registration

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

I am making a use-case for Course Registration where students have to choose their programme, then a list of courses for that programme will be shown for student to choose from. After student has chosen their courses, they register for their class schedule (timetable).

I made this use-case diagram and wanted to know if this is a correct method to do so:
[image]

The Register new account, Generate report & Confirmation E-letter is asked by the question too.

Thank you for all the help

Comment: Correct in which way?

Comment: @qwerty_so I am unsure if for my include, "Register Programme" include in "Register Course" is correct. So my idea is, when user wants to register for course, they are suppose to select their programme, if they have not selected it before. If they have selected it before, it should directly allow them to select their semester and courses. (I added 'Register Semester' as include to my 'Register Course')

Answer (score 0):

Basically your UCs look ok. That is your extend/include are connected the right way. Also the naming is fine.

However, I would not overuse the latter relations. The reason is simply that people tend to start functional analysis instead of synthesizing use cases. A use case is about added value a system brings to its actors. And each added value should be at the front, not somewhere hidden behind include/extend.

---

As always I recommend to read Bittner/Spence about use cases.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The reason I have included so many include is because my tutor specifically mentioned me to have max 4 main functions for my use case. He also mentioned that if I wanted to get extra marks, I had to add extra functions which I included.

Comment: You should recommend the book I mention to your tutor ;-)

Comment: And - you do NOT specify FUNCTIONS in a UC diagram. That's just wrong. It's just added values!